# Audio-to-Text API?

Tags: php, audio, speech-recognition, transcription

Are there any (free) speech-to-text API's that I could use with PHP? (I only know PHP and html/css.)

I'd like to send it an audio file, then have it return the transcription.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any *free* APIs but there are a few relatively inexpensive ones:

- [Quicktate](http://www.quicktate.com/quicktate/api.php)
- PhoneTag
- Twilio

The first two let you supply an MP3, whereas Twilio (which has the best rates) gets input through their own system, so your choice will depend on your application.

(You'll have to Google PhoneTag and Twilio; I can't post more than one link at my current reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

Voice recognition is computationally rather expensive - it's defnitely not the kind of project you'd implement using PHP - OTOH you might create a web-based interface or integrate in a web / IVR type application using PHP as the glue (the voice search on Android is very cool).

So although there are some [off-the-shelf toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux) available, you're probably going to be writing a lot of C code to do anything interesting with them. And how you get on depends a lot on the OS you are using (not stated - example link the first hit from Google).

Comment: THanks for the response. I don't want to code the voice recognition myself. I just have mp3 files which I would like to send to some api, and be returned the text transcription.

Comment: Is that possible? (I found Sphynx4 and MicrosoftSpeech API, but I'm not sure if Sphynx4 would work for me and I have a Mac.)

Comment: Is it possible, by chance, to use Android's Speech-To-Text software for my web app?

Answer (score 0):

[Dynaspeak](http://www.speechatsri.com/products/dynaspeak.shtml) from SRI could work.